# Spring Cloud Contract - Avoiding use of artifactory credentials in the stubrunner config for Maven build

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

We use maven build that has all the passwords set on Jenkins slave required to retrieve the stubs for the consumer test. I find that it requires the user/password for artifactory in the application.yaml (or @AutoConfigureStubRunner in test class). This is a violation in our security.

Is there a way around this where we can avoid specifying the user/password for artifactory or encrypting it? Marcin Grzejszczak?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass it in application yaml. SC-Contract uses the standard Boot property mechanism (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) . You can pass those via system / env properties too.